# Current day phrase meaning "incredibly unpleasant auditory experience"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'd like to use the phrase "fingernails on a chalkboard" in a simile, to describe something as being similar to an incredibly unpleasant auditory experience, except that chalkboards aren't as commonly used as they used to be; "audio feedback screech" is also something that (in my experience) doesn't happen as often in the current day.  Is there a phrase that the most recent generation would be familiar with that conveys the same meaning?

Comment: A dentist's drill is still horrid, though better than it used to be. Train screeching ('rail squeal' I gather it's called). Feedback does still happen: especially in music studios with a crap engineer. It used to be called 'howlround'. Ed Sheeran?

Comment: Do you mean something like *[hyperacusis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperacusis)* or *auditory [hyperaesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperesthesia)*?

Comment: @djs No, not increased sensitivity, but a sound that anyone would find really unpleasant.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the term "sounds like cRap music".  Of course, only us old farts would probably agree with that and we remember chalkboards.

Comment: Grumpy, welcome to SE EL&U! That is an automatic response from the review process of this site. A place your answer arrived at because someone else flagged it as "low quality". Answers that are presented in the form of a question, and with little to no backing/research, are considered comments on this site. If you rephrase it and add more details/backing to it, it would be considered an answer and not a comment. It's not about what I think, but what standards the community has put in place.

Comment: Nails on a chalkboard make a sound that almost everybody finds unpleasant, and certainly the way the idiom "like fingernails on a chalkboard" is used implies that nobody would like the sound even if that's not literally true. A comparison to rap music is not equivalent because although some people hate it many are indifferent and many enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you classify all these noises under **"offensive or obnoxious sounds"**.

What sounds one would include on the list is very subjective.

I, for one, would certainly include **the sound of a spoon scraping the bottom of a saucepan**.  Some people may include the sound of a pneumatic drill on the sidewalk, or the sound of rusty hinges, though.

Comment: A spoon scraping the bottom of a saucepan just makes me hungry.

Comment: "Like fingernails on a chalkboard" (or "nails on a blackboard" as we'd say in Australia) was widely understood to be viscerally unpleasant for everybody, and was used metaphorically even about non-auditory sensations. I don't think the spoon/saucepan thing has the same sort of universal application.